# CAFFE: Cuda Error "(8 vs. 0) invalid device function" when using GPU (GeForce GTX 970)?

Tags: cuda, gpu, caffe

I'm trying to run the CNN Network "CAFFE" on a GTX 970. But I get the error mentioned in the title.

Can someone help?

I posted the issue with more details on the caffe group, but received no hints/answers!

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/sVOfE0qhf_M

**update 1**

In my Makefile.config, I added `-gencode arch=compute_52,code=compute_52`

```
CUDA_ARCH := -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 \
        -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 \
        -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
        -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
        -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
        -gencode arch=compute_50,code=compute_50 \
        -gencode arch=compute_52,code=compute_52
```

But when I try to make, it returns:

```
$make
NVCC src/caffe/layers/cudnn_sigmoid_layer.cu
nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_52'
Makefile:531: recipe for target '.build_release/cuda/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_sigmoid_layer.o' failed
make: *** [.build_release/cuda/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_sigmoid_layer.o] Error 1
```

**update 2**

The NCC version is:

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2014 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Jul_17_21:41:27_CDT_2014
Cuda compilation tools, release 6.5, V6.5.12
```

**update 3**

I'm using CUDA 6.5 with the 346.96 driver

```
libcuda1-346
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.346.96
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.346.96
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libcuda1-346
/usr/share/doc/libcuda1-346/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libcuda1-346/copyright


libcudart6.5
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so.6.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so.6.5.14
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libcudart6.5
/usr/share/doc/libcudart6.5/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libcudart6.5/copyright
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libcudart6.5
```

**update 4**

I found [here](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Grafikkarten/nvidia/nvidia) (page is in German) that Ubuntu 15.04 only supports NVidia GPUs until the 800-series.
What I'm doing right now is update Ubuntu to 15.10, where the NVidia driver version "nvidia-352" is available that is supposed to support a Geforce GTX 970.

I'll post the results here.

**update 5**

It's updated to Ubuntu 15.10. This comes with GCC 5.2, but CAFFE only accepts versions below 4.9.
I installed g++ 4.8 parallel to the existing one I've set the compiler to "g++-4.8" in cmake...

**update 6**

Now the error reads

```
[  1%] Built target proto
[  1%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/util/cuda_compile_generated_math_functions.cu.o
nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_52'
CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_math_functions.cu.o.cmake:206 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/art/Downloads/caffe-master-build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/util/./cuda_compile_generated_math_functions.cu.o


src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:375: recipe for target 'src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/util/cuda_compile_generated_math_functions.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/util/cuda_compile_generated_math_functions.cu.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:218: recipe for target 'src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:116: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**update 7**

My next attempt:

1) Install Ubuntu 15.04

2) Install [CUDA 7.5 directly from nVidia](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)

3) Install [cuDNN 7.0](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn)

4) install [CAFFE](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html)

**that finally worked!!**

Comment: I don't understand the bounty or all the extra edits on this question. You *must* use CUDA 7.0 or newer toolkits with your GPU. The compiler you are using is even telling you this "Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_52'"

Comment: What happens if you just delete the `-gencode arch=compute_52,code=compute_52` line from your Makefile.config (and get rid of the trailing slash on the previous line)?  I'm pretty sure the 346.96 can JIT from compute_50 to the needed code for your GPU.

Comment: There is also a [CUDA 6.5 version with support for GTX 9xx](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads-geforce-gtx9xx) available, but generally, I would recommend using CUDA 7.5 at this time.

Comment: @talonmies, what I did not know/understand was, which versions etc. I need to install to get it to work. I updated the description (update 7) for what I will try now. Is that a good way?

Comment: @RobertCrovella, that was the initial configuration, the "compute_52" was added manually to the Makefile.config

Comment: @S.H: Yes, either CUDA 7.0 or CUDA 7.5 will work correctly with your GPU. Caffe definitely supports CUDA 7.0 (they say so on their website). I am no expert on Caffe and can't tell you whether CUDA 7.5 will work. My guess is that it will. I have edited the toolkit requirements into my existing answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whenever the CUDA runtime API returns "Invalid Device Function", it means you are using code which wasn't built for the architecture you are trying to run it on (and doesn't have a JIT path).

You probably need to check your CAFFE `Makefile.config` to make sure it is set for the correct architecture, by making sure that `CUDA_ARCH` includes `-gencode arch=compute_52,code=compute_52`.

Because you are using a compute capability 52 device, you must use CUDA 7 or newer with your GPU. The CUDA 6.5 toolkit you are using cannot generate code for your GPU, and the CUDA 6.5 driver cannot JIT recompile lower compute capability code into something which will run on your GPU. This is a not negotiable requirement for your hardware.

Comment: Du you have any ideas regarding the update I wrote above?

Comment: @S.H: That would mean you have an incompatible CUDA version for your GPU, and that might be the root cause of your problems.

Comment: I'm using the deviceQuery-sample from cuda to determine the device properties (see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/sVOfE0qhf_M). Doesn't this make sure that I can communicate with the GPU correctly?

Comment: That isn't the problem. The problem is that the driver and compiler in CUDA 6.5 don't know how to produce native code which can run on your GPU. You will have to upgrade

Comment: Get the same error with `CUDA V8.0.44` and `CAFFE V1.0.0-rc3` on docker `caffe8:gpu`. I'm not sure why these versions does not match then according to this solution. Also the `nvidia-docker run -ti  --rm caffe:gpu caffe --version` neither works.